# How to detect a closed connection on a socket without a blocking call in boost asio

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio, eof

I've written a tcp communication scheme using boost asio and it works quite fine if I use a separate thread for the `io_service::run()`. However, the communicator should also be used as part of an MPI-parallel program (please do not question this), where forking and threading is not a good idea and may not be permitted.

Therefor, the communicator has a function `work()` which calls `io_service::run_one`. Now, if I directly use `async_read`, it will be blocking is the call to `run_one` until something is read or an error occurs. So I wrote the `check_available` function shown below that first checks if there's something on the socket before calling the `async_read` in my function `read_message_header`.

This also works smoothly until the peer closes the connection. Unfortunately, this seems not to be flagged as an eof error by `socket::available(error)` like it is the case in the`async_read` and it returns 0 as the number of available bytes so that `read_message_header` is never called, which would then detect the eof.  Also checking `socket::is_open()` did not work for this purpose, because only the peer's sockets are closed and not the receiving socket on this instance.

```
void TCPConnection::check_availble() {
    if(! socket_.is_open()) {
        handle_read_error(boost::asio::error::eof);
    }
    boost::system::error_code error;
    size_t nbytes=socket_.available(error); // does not detect the eof
    if(error)
        handle_read_error(error);
    if(nbytes>0)
        read_message_header();
    else
        socket_.get_io_service().post(
                boost::bind(
                        &TCPConnection::check_availble,
                        shared_from_this()
                )
        );
}
```

Is there a way to detect the eof without any blocking calls?

Comment: Where does it say it should be 'flagged as an eof error by `socket::available(error)`'? You have to execute a read to detect EOF on a socket.

Answer (score 0):

I've couple of remarks to make:

> which calls io_service::run_one. Now, if I directly use async_read, it
>   will be blocking is the call to run_one until something is read or an
>   error occurs

You can easily subvert this blocking behaviour by creating a fake `work<>` object and post it into `io_service` queue, so as long as there are handlers to execute, the poll won't wait for any events: just return immediately.

speaking about `size_t nbytes=socket_.available(error);`; `avilable()` returns number of bytes that are available to read (may be without blocking), and as mentioned in a comment: perhaps, you need to read the ready-bytes to see EOF, but `avilable()` has nothing to do with it.